# Deleting a file that is older than x number of days using a batch file in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been trying to write a batch file that removes files that are older than `x` number of days. I have a backup directory `E:\Backup2` that contains a number of sub-folders `Alresco`, `Postgres` and `Sybase`.

These sub-folders contain different internal structuring of files but I don't think this should affect the script as I only need it to look through every file in the `Backup2` directory, and if it is older than `x` days then delete that file.

So far I have the following but I cannot get it to work:

```
FORFILES /P "E:\Backup2" /S /D -2 /C "CMD DEL /F /Q @PATH"
```

where `2` defines how old a file must be in days before it can be deleted.

When I execute the command in `CMD` all of the files remain without any error being reported.

What is interesting however is that when I output to a log file, it reports the directory where the first file is located..

When I first ran the command the log file reported `E:\Backup2\Alfresco\25072015` however when I moved a log file to the root directory and re-ran the comman the log file reported `E:\Backup2` which suggests the command is finding the first log file it needs to delete and then breaks.

Comment: [Relevant](https://xkcd.com/1168).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) they have these examples:

```
    Examples:

Delete the testfile if it is is 5 days old or older:
C:\> forfiles /m testfile.txt /c "cmd /c Del testfile.txt " /d -5

Find .xls file that were last modified 30 days ago or older 
C:\> FORFILES /M *.xls /C "cmd /c echo @path was changed 30 days ago" /D -30

List the size of all .doc files:
C:\> FORFILES /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
```

Compared to your code you seem to miss /c when calling cmd del, so your code should be:

```
FORFILES /P "E:\Backup2" /S /D -2 /C "CMD /c DEL /F /Q @PATH"
```

Comment: Note that calling CMD /c creates a new thread for each time/file matched by forfiles